# AppStore problem with language of iOS Cordova apps always English and German

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I uploaded the past months several iOS apps made with Cordova and when they were published all shown in its app details that the languages are English and German but I want to display Spanish because the apps are oriented to the spanish market.

An image as example:
[image]

Is there a way to change this? Via Xcode or iTunes Connect...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the app's Info.plist, add an array named CFBundleLocalizations and add strings with the names of the localizations you have available in your app, such as ‘es’.

> CFBundleLocalizations (Array - iOS, OS X) identifies the localizations handled manually by your app. If your executable is unbundled or does not use the existing bundle localization mechanism, you can include this key to specify the localizations your app does handle.
>
> Each entry in this property’s array is a string identifying the language name or ISO language designator of the supported localization. See “Language and Locale Designations” in Internationalization and Localization Guide in Internationalization Documentation for information on how to specify language designators.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Comment: I already did this and this only works at least for me to properly show the "Copy, Paste, Select, Select All.." of an input in Spanish but nothing changed in the App Store.

Comment: @xmarston, What about now? This is what I was going to do too.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei it seems that if you do this in a new app works but for an existing app in the App Store no.

Comment: @xmarston, And did you find a way to make it work for an existing app?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei nope, sorry. Still looking for a solution.